# Why does iodine have different colors in different media?

Tags: molecular-orbital-theory, color, halides

It is violet in trichloromethane, but brown in water. why? In the Shriver Atkins book, they tried to explain this using *Molecular Orbital Theory* which was not clear to me

Comment: Some interesting information can be found in [this related question](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/27609/1499).

Answer (score 1):

color is result of electron transfer between orbitals and anything that affect energy of these orbitals can change color of that specie, so iodine in different mediums have different interactions and because of that iodine orbitals have different energies in different medium,so iodine have different color in different mediums.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! Take the [tour] to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) using $\LaTeX$ syntax. For more information in general have a look at the [help]. Could you elaborate a little bit more, I cannot follow your thoughts. How do the interactions with the medium influence the energies of iodine?